# Passing object to props in a View instance > dynamically load Component from external variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tried with props and PropsData but it is not working :/

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Hello from '@/components/Hello.vue'

export function createComponent(selector, params) {
  const test = {name: 'Test'};

  new Vue({
    el: selector,
    render: app => app(selector, {
      propsData: test
    })
  })
}
```

I can't find why this is not possible even with some console.log here and there, i'm not really confident with VueJS so is there a way to do that ?

### Edit:

After some testings, props was correctly passed by what I wrote, It seems that I am not correctly passing the component name to the Vue instance:

Here is how my code works (or how i want it to works at least...):

#### Random php file:

```
<?php
$selector = "Hello";
$data = json_encode(['name' => 'from PHP'])
?>
<div id="<?= $selector; ?>-component"></div>
<script>
  createComponent(<?= $selector; ?>, <?php return $data; ?>) // I tried "$selector" format, but doesn't work either.
</script>
```

#### My main js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Hello from '@/components/Hello'

export function createComponent(selector, params) {
  new Vue({
    el: '#' + selector + '-component',
    render: app => app(selector, { // If I replace selector by Hello, it works, but that's not what I want.
      props: params
    })
  })
}
```

> In this file I tried some tricks to call the component from 'selector' but the console tells me: `ReferenceError: Hello is not defined`

But as we can see Hello is clearly define at the top of the file.

#### My single file vue component:

```
<template>
    <h1>
        Hello {{ name }}!!
    </h1>
</template>

<script>
  module.exports = {
    props: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        default: 'World'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I simplified my php code to show you the case so there may have some errors, I haven't tried it.

The mistake must come from the syntax, or else I get it wrong.

PS: I hate JS syntax :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export function createComponent(selector, propsData) {

  let instance = new Vue({
    el: document.createElement('div'),
    render(createElement) {
     return createElement(
      'h' + this.level,   // tag name
      this.$slots.default // array of children
     )
    },
    propsData
  })

  document.body.querySelector(selector).appendChild(instance.$el);
}
```

Assuming that you want to create dynamically VueJS instance and append it to dom. Also propsData object you need to move out from render function. Render function is optional, you can always use template string...

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your time but I cleaned up a bit my code and the problem wasn't from the props, what I did work properly, it comes from the selector: I will edit my question to clarify what I'm trying to do :) (btw my webpack configuration don't let me the possibility to use the document attribute to test your answer, do I need to add something like 'library: "vanillaJS"' in my configurations?)

Comment: It's weird that you don't have access to document, you obviously don't do SSR... However, no need for any additional library vanillaJS... About dynamic components maybe this article will help you https://coligo.io/dynamic-components-in-vuejs/

Comment: Hi, I could access to document, webpack sent me a weird error but I could get over it. Anyway, after hours of research I did a minimalist repo of what I found (I saw this article a little later after your first answer), I think I'm not that far of what I wanted to do but it still doesn't work, if you have the time to review it, that would be really nice :) => My repository: https://github.com/Daivir/Dynamic-Vue-Components

Comment: @Daivir I have been bussy so I couldn't answer you faster... Main mistake you have made in `index.html` file where your `<script type="text/javascript" src="build/main.min.js"></script>` tag is before `<div id="app"></div>`, so just move that after div element. After that just modify computed prop in App.vue to method and that's all... I think that this computed prop is redundant because you can use directly component prop... I've created fixed copy of your example on https://codesandbox.io/s/vyx92yx3vl so look that for more info.

Comment: Oh! Please don't say that, you really helped me! It works like a charm now, thanks for your time! I'll try to handle datas now, maybe i'll update my answer later for those who are potentially interested. I saw somewhere vue-router is based from this concept maybe i'll take a look when I'll be more comfortable with vuejs. Cheers!